# "http://" to anchor in chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, anchor

I'm doing a simple chat. When user sends message to server I want to parse this message. Whenever I find `http://****` I want to convert it into a `a` tag, but all other characters need to be escaped, so that a user won't mess with html.

There are probably many ways to obtain it. Using some fancy regular expressions would be nice. Any ideas?

Note that I'm using Node.js.

Comment: @Neal: Identifying URLs in plain text with regex is fine

Comment: @Neal: I just can't see how this is related to my question.

Comment: @Neal: what is that? Instead of linking to the actual stackoverflow post, you link to your own blog which presents an image of the post, but no further text or comments? Is there any added value, or are you just trying to spam your blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running each line of chat through this function before it is output to the user:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Source: [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: Almost there. But at the same time I want to escape other chars. So for example: `<span>test http://google.com </span>` will show everything with the link interchanged.

Comment: Oh, I just encode entire message at the begining and *THEN* use your parser. I think it works fine. Thank you! :)